# Running an alphanet node

Tags: alphanet, setup

So I want to dive into the tezos project a little, therefore I tried to set up a tezos node running the alphanet to fiddle around a little.

I followed the official documentation and used docker on my mac to get the latest containers for running the alpha net.

So far so good:

```
dev-imac-pro:tezos andy$ ./alphanet.sh status
Node is running
Baker is not running
Endorser is not running
The script is up to date.
```

But running `andys-imac-pro:tezos andy$ ./alphanet.sh client identity generate`throws:

`Error:
  Unrecognized command.
  Try using the man command to get more information.`

So It looks like the node is not running?
There is also no `$HOME/.tezos-node/`just an `$HOME/.tezos-alphanet/`folder.

What do I do wrong?
How do I run the tezos-node command using the alphanet.sh script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tezos Alphanet is now called "Babylonnet". Future Testnets will get the name of the actual active (or future) protocol.

Follow [this](https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html) guide to setup a Babylon Testnet node.

Answer (score 0):

Use

`sudo ./alphanet.sh shell`

Than

`tezos-node identity generate`

But even after this i got `Too few connections(0)` error.
Please, write here if you will got this error too. 
You can join issue discussion here https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/614